# Когда перечесляют через сout елементы массива double вместо чисел -1.45682e+144 и не критичная ошибка C6385

Tags: c++, массивы, double

```
void S(double* x ) {
    for (int i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
        n[i] = x[i];
cout << n[i] << endl;
        
    }
}
```

вот откуда берется х

```
double* GetInput(const char * filename, unsigned int h,unsigned int w) {
    sf::Image image;
    vector<double> in;
    image.loadFromFile(filename);
    
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < h; ++i) {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < w; ++j)
        {
            sf::Color c;
            c = image.getPixel(j,i );
            in.push_back((int)(c.r + c.b + c.g) / 3);
            //int u = (int)((c.r + c.b + c.g) / 3);
            //cout << u << endl;
        }
    }
    double* input = &in[0];
    //copy(in.begin(), in.end(), input);
    return input;
    
}
```

а l это костанта которая равна w*h
и текст ошибки
вот текст ошибки серьезность код описание проект файл строка состояние подавления предупреждение c6385 чтение недопустимых данных из "x": доступный для чтения объем равен "l 8" байт, однако считать можно только "16" байт. source.cpp 156

```
int main(){
    N g(28*28);//это и есть 'l'
    g.S(GetInput("f.png", 28, 28));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: а как задаются `n` и `l` - может если это константные вещи компилятор видит, что вы за границы массива вылезаете

Comment: вот текст ошибки серьезность код описание проект файл строка состояние подавления предупреждение c6385 чтение недопустимых данных из "x": доступный для чтения объем равен "l 8" байт, однако считать можно только "16" байт. source.cpp 152

Comment: за рамки не выхожу это я проверил , а l это константа

Comment: Вы можете выложить полный код, чтобы мы увидели какой `x` вы передаете, что за `n`, чему равно `l`?

Comment: выложенная дополнительно функция `GetInput` мало что говорит - где вызов `S`, где опять же `n` и `l`?

Comment: @vlad не могли бы мы как-то связаться? У меня есть ответ на ваш последний вопрос (который закрыли) Например можно попробовать через [чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118825/vlad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Т.к. вы возвращаете `double* input`, а не `vector<double> in` при завершении этой функции у `in` вызывается деструктор, где происходит удаление данных, а вы возвращаете указатель на эти данные, следовательно в `input` после завершения функции будут не определенные значения, ну и в целом вы возвращаете пустой указатель.

Чтобы решить эту проблему нужно сначала под `input` выделить новую память куда мы будем копировать данные из вектора, а потом раскомментировать строчку :)) :

```
double* input = new double[w * h];
copy(in.begin(), in.end(), input);
```

то есть произвести полное копирование данных.

Comment: увы не помогло (

Comment: @vlad тогда выкладывайте наверно уже вообще весь код. И учтите что все таки, то что я написал в ответе является ошибкой.

Comment: спасибо но я уже нашел решение еще раз спасибо

Answer (score 0):

а вот это помогло

```
 /*double* input = &in[0];
        copy(in.begin(), in.end(), input);*/
        double* input = new double[w * h];
        for (int i = 0; i < w * h; i++) {
            input[i] = in[i];
        }
        return input;
```

Comment: Это и есть полное копирование :), то есть раскоментированная строчка не помогла вам?

Comment: не помогла почему то

Comment: скидывать полный код ?

Comment: нужно под `input` выделить новую память. То есть `double* input = new double[w * h]` а потом уже делать копирование. В общем ваш цикл просто заменить на `copy(in.begin(), in.end(), input)`

Comment: так тоже работает , спасибо еще раз